# Django 1.8 Migrations - "NoneType" object has no attribute "_meta"

Tags: python, django

Attempting to migrate a project from Django 1.7 to 1.8. After wrestling with code errors, I'm able to get migrations to run. However, when I try to migrate, I'm given the error "'NoneType' object has no attribute '_meta'"

There's no reference in the traceback to any of my apps, so I'm unsure of where exactly to go about looking for the bug (as well as which code to include here so I can be more helpful to those trying to help me)

Here's the full text of the traceback

```
(venv)rtownley@ubuntu:~/Projects/sparrow1/NJ$ ./manage.py makemigrations
No changes detected
(venv)rtownley@ubuntu:~/Projects/sparrow1/NJ$ ./manage.py migrate
Operations to perform:
  Synchronize unmigrated apps: staticfiles, editor, djcelery, messages, getty, kombu_transport_django, debug_toolbar, utils, locking, petro, tokenapi, grappelli, django_extensions, selectable
  Apply all migrations: adops, taxonomy, issues, editorial, contenttypes, authors, auth, comms, membership, sessions, bento, urlalias, accounts, breaking_news, easy_thumbnails, images, admin, pages, documents, events
Synchronizing apps without migrations:
  Creating tables...
    Running deferred SQL...
  Installing custom SQL...
Running migrations:
  Rendering model states...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/rtownley/Projects/sparrow1/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 338, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/rtownley/Projects/sparrow1/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 330, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/rtownley/Projects/sparrow1/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 390, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/home/rtownley/Projects/sparrow1/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 441, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home/rtownley/Projects/sparrow1/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 221, in handle
    executor.migrate(targets, plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/home/rtownley/Projects/sparrow1/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 104, in migrate
    state = migration.mutate_state(state, preserve=do_run)
  File "/home/rtownley/Projects/sparrow1/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/migrations/migration.py", line 83, in mutate_state
    operation.state_forwards(self.app_label, new_state)
  File "/home/rtownley/Projects/sparrow1/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/migrations/operations/fields.py", line 51, in state_forwards
    state.reload_model(app_label, self.model_name_lower)
  File "/home/rtownley/Projects/sparrow1/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/migrations/state.py", line 97, in reload_model
    related_models = get_related_models_recursive(old_model)
  File "/home/rtownley/Projects/sparrow1/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/migrations/state.py", line 57, in get_related_models_recursive
    rel_app_label, rel_model_name = rel_mod._meta.app_label, rel_mod._meta.model_name
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_meta'
```

Other pieces that could potentially be at play:
-I have a custom handler that listens for the save event, serializes the data, and creates an identical object in Mongo
-Operating out of a virtual environment running Python3.4

Any thoughts on where to go about hunting for the error? Thanks, and sorry I can't provide more code yet!

Comment: Showing the code for the migration would go a long way, too.

Comment: Looks like perhaps one of your models is related to a model that does not exist?

Comment: Ughhhh that was it. A model I had deleted was re-added by another person during a Git merge. Thanks for setting me on the right track!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to meiamsome, I figured it out: one of my models had a ForeignKey relationship to a model that no longer existed (I had removed it, and a Git merge had added it back). Thanks for the help all!

Answer (score 0):

Doubt this will help anyone but I had single quotes around my model name instead of referencing the class model object itself. Removing the quotes seemed to help.