# Django 1.8 Migrations - "'NoneType' object has no attribute '_meta'"

Tags: python, django, django-migrations

I've seen [Django 1.8 Migrations - "NoneType" object has no attribute "_meta"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29549180/django-1-8-migrations-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-meta) but the solution proposed there didn't appear to be the case...

I'm working on a Django application, and receive this traceback every time I try to run "migrate" ("makemigrations" works just fine, as does "syncdb" (if I blow away the database and delete the migrations folder).

```
    (molivenv)moli@moli:~/moli$ ./manage.py migrate
    Operations to perform:
      Synchronize unmigrated apps: humanize, util, staticfiles, messages
      Apply all migrations: core, contenttypes, sessions, admin, auth
    Synchronizing apps without migrations:
      Creating tables...
        Running deferred SQL...
      Installing custom SQL...
    Running migrations:
      Rendering model states...Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "./manage.py", line 10, in 
        execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
      File "/home/moli/moli/molivenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 338, in execute_from_command_line
        utility.execute()
      File "/home/moli/moli/molivenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 330, in execute
        self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
      File "/home/moli/moli/molivenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 390, in run_from_argv
        self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
      File "/home/moli/moli/molivenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 441, in execute
        output = self.handle(*args, **options)
      File "/home/moli/moli/molivenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 221, in handle
        executor.migrate(targets, plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
      File "/home/moli/moli/molivenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 104, in migrate
        state = migration.mutate_state(state, preserve=do_run)
      File "/home/moli/moli/molivenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/migrations/migration.py", line 83, in mutate_state
        operation.state_forwards(self.app_label, new_state)
      File "/home/moli/moli/molivenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/migrations/operations/fields.py", line 51, in state_forwards
        state.reload_model(app_label, self.model_name_lower)
      File "/home/moli/moli/molivenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/migrations/state.py", line 97, in reload_model
        related_models = get_related_models_recursive(old_model)
      File "/home/moli/moli/molivenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/migrations/state.py", line 57, in get_related_models_recursive
        rel_app_label, rel_model_name = rel_mod._meta.app_label, rel_mod._meta.model_name
    AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_meta'
```

These are my models (sorry for the length, but I can't see any hint at where the problem is in the traceback, so I thought I'd be thorough):

```
    from datetime import date

    from django.db import models
    from django.contrib.auth.models import User
    from django.contrib.contenttypes.fields import GenericForeignKey
    from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType

    from gm2m import GM2MField
    from gm2m.deletion import DO_NOTHING
    from localflavor.us.models import PhoneNumberField, USPostalCodeField, USZipCodeField


    class Organization(models.Model):
        is_active = models.BooleanField(blank=True, default=True)
        name = models.CharField(max_length=255, help_text='For example, "Acme"', verbose_name="Short name")
        full_legal_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, help_text='For example, "Acme Widgets and Blivets, Inc."')
        tax_id = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, verbose_name="Tax ID")

        website = models.URLField(blank=True)

        address = models.ForeignKey('Address', blank=True, null=True, related_name="organization_address_set", verbose_name="Primary address")
        mailing_address = models.ForeignKey('Address', blank=True, null=True, related_name="organization_mailing_address_set")

        def __str__(self):
            return self.name

        @property
        def model_verbose_name(self):
            return self._meta.verbose_name

        def get_mailing_address(self):
            return self.mailing_address or self.address

        def get_absolute_url(self):
            return "/organizations/edit/%s/" % self.pk


    class UserProfile(models.Model):
        user = models.ForeignKey(User)
        avatar = models.ImageField(blank=True, upload_to='user-avatars')

        def __str__(self):
            return str(self.user)

        def avatar_url(self):
            if self.avatar:
                return self.avatar.url
            else:
                return "%suser-icon.png" % STATIC_URL

        def get_absolute_url(self):
            return "/users/%s/" % self.pk


    class AuditedModel(models.Model):
        added_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
        changed_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
        added_by = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile, blank=True, null=True)
        organization = models.ForeignKey(Organization, blank=True, null=True, related_name="%(app_label)s_%(class)s_ownership")
        is_active = models.BooleanField(blank=True, default=True)

        class Meta:
            abstract = True

        @property
        def model_verbose_name(self):
            return self._meta.verbose_name


    class Contact(AuditedModel):
        first_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
        middle_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
        last_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

        photo = models.ImageField(blank=True, upload_to='contact_photos/', null=True, max_length=500)

        dob = models.DateField(blank=True, verbose_name="DOB", null=True, help_text="Date of Birth")
        dod = models.DateField(blank=True, verbose_name="DOD", null=True, help_text="Date of Death")

        email = models.EmailField(blank=True)
        office_phone = PhoneNumberField(blank=True)
        home_phone = PhoneNumberField(blank=True)
        mobile_phone = PhoneNumberField(blank=True)
        other_phone = PhoneNumberField(blank=True)
        fax = PhoneNumberField(blank=True)

        skype = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
        twitter = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
        facebook = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
        linkedin = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, verbose_name="LinkedIn")

        company = models.ForeignKey('Company', blank=True, null=True)
        title = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
        department = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)

        mailing_street = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, verbose_name="Mailing Street")
        mailing_city = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, verbose_name="Mailing City")
        mailing_state = USPostalCodeField(blank=True, verbose_name="Mailing State")
        mailing_zip = USZipCodeField(blank=True, verbose_name="Mailing Zip")

        comments = models.ManyToManyField('Comment', blank=True)


        def __str__(self):
            return " ".join([x for x in [self.get_prefix_display(), self.first_name, self.middle_name, self.last_name, self.get_suffix_display()] if x])

        def photo_url(self):
            if self.photo:
                return self.photo.url
            else:
                return "%suser-icon.png" % STATIC_URL

        def get_absolute_url(self):
            return "/contacts/%s/" % self.pk

        class Meta:
            ordering = ['last_name', 'first_name', 'last_name']



    class Company(AuditedModel):
        name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
        photo = models.ImageField(blank=True, upload_to='company_photos/', null=True, max_length=500)

        email = models.EmailField(blank=True)
        phone = PhoneNumberField(blank=True)

        twitter = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
        facebook = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
        linkedin = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, verbose_name="LinkedIn")

        mailing_street = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, verbose_name="Mailing Street")
        mailing_city = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, verbose_name="Mailing City")
        mailing_state = USPostalCodeField(blank=True, verbose_name="Mailing State")
        mailing_zip = USZipCodeField(blank=True, verbose_name="Mailing Zip")

        other_street = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, verbose_name="Other Street")
        other_city = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, verbose_name="Other City")
        other_state = USPostalCodeField(blank=True, verbose_name="Other State")
        other_zip = USZipCodeField(blank=True, verbose_name="Other ZIP")

        comments = models.ManyToManyField('Comment', blank=True)


        def __str__(self):
            return self.name

        def photo_url(self):
            if self.photo:
                return self.photo.url
            else:
                return "%scompany-icon.png" % STATIC_URL

        def get_absolute_url(self):
            return "/companies/%s/" % self.pk

        class Meta:
            ordering = ['name',]



    class Comment(AuditedModel):
        comment = models.TextField()

        def __str__(self):
            return "Comment made on %s by %s" % (self.added_on, self.added_by)

        class Meta:
            ordering = ['-added_on',]


    class Address(AuditedModel):
        street = models.CharField(max_length=255)
        city = models.CharField(max_length=255)
        state = USPostalCodeField()
        zip = USZipCodeField(blank=True, verbose_name="ZIP")

        def __str__(self):
            return "%s, %s, %s%s" % (self.street, self.city, self.state, self.zip and " %s" % self.zip or '')

        def associated(self):
            ret = []    # Could use yield, but template doesn't let you do |length then...
            for c in self.organization_address_set.all():
                ret.append({'model': Organization, 'instance': c, 'field': 'address', 'field_display': 'Primary Address'})
            for c in self.organization_mailing_address_set.all():
                ret.append({'model': Organization, 'instance': c, 'field': 'mailing_address', 'field_display': 'Mailing Address'})
            return ret


    class Photo(AuditedModel):
        photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='photo-library/')
        caption = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=500)

        def __str__(self):
            return self.caption or self.photo.file.name


    class UserFile(AuditedModel):
        file = models.FileField(upload_to='user-files/')
        description = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=500)

        def __str__(self):
            return self.description or self.file.file.name


    class Item(AuditedModel):
        name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
        description = models.TextField(blank=True)
        item_number = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
        main_photo = models.ForeignKey('Photo', blank=True, null=True, related_name="%(app_label)s_%(class)s_ownership")
        other_photos = models.ManyToManyField('Photo', blank=True, related_name="%(app_label)s_%(class)s_other_ownership")
        attachments = models.ManyToManyField('UserFile', blank=True)
        comments = models.TextField(blank=True)

        class Meta:
            abstract = True


    class RawMaterial(Item):
        supplier = models.ForeignKey(Company, blank=True, null=True)
        spn = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, help_text="Supplier's Part Number")
        inventoried = models.BooleanField(blank=True, default=True)
        um = models.ForeignKey('UnitOfMeasure', blank=True, null=True)

        def __str__(self):
            return self.name


    class RawMaterialQuantity(AuditedModel):
        raw_material = models.ForeignKey('RawMaterial')
        qty = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=5, max_digits=50)
        unit = models.ForeignKey('UnitOfMeasure', blank=True, null=True)

        def __str__(self):
            return "%s %s of %s" % (self.qty, self.unit, self.raw_material)


    class PurchasedRawMaterial(AuditedModel):
        raw_material_quantity = models.ForeignKey('RawMaterialQuantity')
        price = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=50)
        purchase_date = models.DateField()
        lot_number = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)

        def __str__(self):
            if self.lot_number:
                return "%s purchased on %s (lot #%s)" % (self.raw_material_quantity, self.purchase_date, self.lot_number)
            else:
                return "%s purchased on %s" % (self.raw_material_quantity, self.purchase_date)


    class UnitOfMeasure(AuditedModel):
        name = models.CharField(max_length=255, help_text="For example, 'Ounces'")
        abbreviation = models.CharField(max_length=40, help_text="For example, 'Oz.'")

        def __str__(self):
            return self.abbreviation

        class Meta:
            ordering = ['abbreviation',]


    class Assembly(Item):
        mpn = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, help_text="Manufacturer's Part Number")  # If purchased
        price = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=50, null=True) # If purchased
        production_steps = models.ManyToManyField('ProductionStep', blank=True) # If made

        def __str__(self):
            return self.name


    class PurchasedAssembly(AuditedModel):
        assembly = models.ForeignKey('Assembly')
        purchase_price = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=50)
        purchase_date = models.DateField()
        serial_number = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)

        def __str__(self):
            if self.serial_number:
                return "%s purchased on %s (serial #%s)" % (self.assembly, self.purchase_date, self.serial_number)
            else:
                return "%s purchased on %s" % (self.assembly, self.purchase_date)


    class AssembledAssembly(AuditedModel):
        assembly = models.ForeignKey('Assembly')
        assembly_date = models.DateField()
        serial_number = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)

        def __str__(self):
            if self.serial_number:
                return "%s assembled on %s (serial #%s)" % (self.assembly, self.assembly_date, self.serial_number)
            else:
                return "%s assembled on %s" % (self.assembly, self.assembly_date)


    class AssemblyQuantity(AuditedModel):
        assembly_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
        assembly_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
        assembly_object = GenericForeignKey('assembly_type', 'assembly_id')
        qty = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=5, max_digits=50)

        def __str__(self):
            return "%s %s" % (self.qty, self.assembly_object.name)


    class Product(Item):
        resell = models.BooleanField(default=False, help_text="Do you resell this item (rather than make it)?")
        mpn = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, help_text="Manufacturer's Part Number")
        price = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=50, null=True)
        production_steps = models.ManyToManyField('ProductionStep', blank=True)

        def __str__(self):
            return self.name


    class ProductionStep(models.Model):
        order = models.IntegerField()
        time = models.DecimalField(help_text="How much time does this step take, in minutes?", decimal_places=5, max_digits=50)
        materials = GM2MField(on_delete=DO_NOTHING, blank=True)  # RawMaterialQuantity, AssemblyQuantity

        def __str__(self):
            return "Step %s" % self.order
```

GM2MField comes from here https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-gm2m/

Comment: To make it even lengthier: can you show your migration files for your `core` app? Does `manage.py check` return anything about relations?

Comment: I talked with Steve earlier, everything works when commenting out ProductionStep.materials. Also, it fails on Django 1.7 in addition to 1.8.

Comment: Turned out to be a bug in django-gm2m...
https://bitbucket.org/tkhyn/django-gm2m/issue/3/issue-with-migrations